# Can constexpr function return pointer of local object?

Tags: c++, c++14

A constexpr function is defined as (c++14)

> A constexpr function must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - it must not be virtual
> - its return type must be LiteralType each of its parameters must be LiteralType
> - there exists at least one set of  argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an    evaluated subexpression of a
>     core constant expression (for    constructors, use in a constant
>     initializer is sufficient) (since    C++14). No diagnostic is required
>     for a violation of this bullet.
>
> the function body must be either deleted or defaulted or contain any
>   statements except:
>
> - an asm declaration
> - a goto statement
> - a statement with a label other than case and default
> - a try-block
> - a definition of a variable of non-literal type
> - a definition of a variable of static or thread storage duration
> - a definition of a variable for which no initialization is performed.

Now following func1 meets the requirement and compiles

```
constexpr int * func1 (int a)
{
  int b = 4;
  return &b;
}
int main()
{
    constexpr int * a = func1(3);
    int arr[*a];  
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Now my question is how come func1 is constexpr. How does it know address of local variable at compile time?

I am using gcc 6.4.0

Comment: I think you may be too lax in interpreting the third bullet ("*there exists at least one set of argument values..."*) as being satisfied.

Comment: my question remains valid. How can compiler know address of local variable at compile time (irrespective of argument value)?

Comment: func1 is not a constexpr!

Comment: Your question is only valid under the premise all bullets are satisfied. Since the third one is likely not, and no diagnostic is required for that case, the answer is you get yourself undefined behavior in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Please help in understanding this. third bullets says  atleast one set of arguments? No combination of argument make function constexpr.

Comment: what happens to `b` after `func1()` returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does it know address of local variable at compile time?

It doesn't.

The third bullet in your quote is never satisfied:

> There exists at least one set of argument values such that an
>   invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a
>   core constant expression (for constructors, use in a constant
>   initializer is sufficient) (since C++14). **No diagnostic is required
>   for a violation of this bullet.**

The compiler just doesn't complain about it because it's not required to, until you make it complain by trying to use `func1` inside something that requires a correct `constexpr` function, for example:

```
std::array<int, func(3)> d;
```

This won't compile and your compiler will tell you why.

Comment: Ok. I think compilers should start complaining. I think it is defect in standard then

Comment: @code707 The standard states "no diagnostic is required" so you should blame the standard, not the compilers.

Comment: @SombreroChicken in cases like this, accepting or not is a quality-of-implementation issue. In more complex cases, it can be undecidable. The standard is correct to NDR that bullet

Answer (score 4):

> Now my question is how come func1 is constexpr.

Are you sure?

Try asking a compile time value saving it in a `constexpr` variable; by example

```
constexpr int * a = func1(3);
```

You should get a list of error/warnings like (from my clang++ 3.8.1)

```
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:7:11: warning: address of stack memory associated with
      local variable 'b' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
  return &b;
          ^
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:11:21: error: constexpr variable 'a' must be
      initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr int * a = func1(3);
                    ^   ~~~~~~~~
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:11:21: note: pointer to 'b' is not a constant
      expression
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:6:7: note: declared here
  int b = 4;
      ^
```

Well, actually, from my g++ 6.3.0 I get only a warning

```
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp: In function ‘constexpr int* func1(int)’:
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:7:7: warning: address of local variable ‘b’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   int b = 4;
       ^
```

Comment: I compiled with g++ 6.4.0 and it compiled and output 0.

Comment: gcc 8.1.0 return 0 (with warning: address of local variable ‘b’ returned)

Comment: @code707 - interesting; I suppose the point is "No diagnostic is required for a violation of this bullet"; so the code is wrong but the compiler isn't required to say it.

Comment: @code707 Yikes. Indeed, GCC accepts that, even in its current 8.1 version. I *think* it translates a return of a local variable to a warning + a return of a null pointer (since the local variable can't be used anyway after the function returns), but then treats that null pointer as constant.

Comment: @max66 what compiler you are using ?

Comment: @code707 - anyway, from g++ 6.3.0 I get a warning "address of local variable ‘b’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]" (from `int b = 4;`)

Comment: Now.. we have two compiler giving different results. If you go to answers below, looks like g++ is right as per standard. But I think clang behavior is more appropriate. Should this be filed as change(defect?) in standard ?

Comment: @code707 - I suppose also g++ is correct: "no diagnostic is required". But I'm not a language-lawyer.

Comment: @max66 GCC can get away with accepting the function definition, but if the initialiser for a `constexpr` variable is not a constant expression, then a diagnostic *is* required per [dcl.constexpr]p9. It's iffy whether the diagnostic that it issues for the function definition is good enough to qualify also for the variable initialisation.

Comment: @hvd - that is also true... no problem for a function tagged `constexpr` that isn't really `constexpr`. But should give an error when a compile time value is required.

Comment: I modified example and used constexpr where constexpr is required, it still compiles..but give run time crash.. it is a definitely bug in gcc

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when `func1()` returns, `b` goes out of scope.
Thus, any usage relating to `b` outside `func1()` is *undefined behavior*.

```
constexpr int * func1 (int a)
{
  int b = 4; // remember: b is non-static
  return &b;
}

int * a = func1(3); // b is out of scope here
```

Also, from [expr.const](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#5.2):

A core *constant expression* satisfies:

> (5.2) if the value is of *pointer* type, it contains the address of an
>   object with **`static`** storage duration, the address past the end of
>   such an object, the address of a function, or a null pointer value

Which in your case, `b` is not `static`, which means `func1()` is **not** a *constant expression*.

Comment: yes, that is ambiguity. who is right g++ or clang ? Does standard needs to be changed to have more clarity ?